# How to ensure accessibility of pod

Tags: kubernetes

I want to create a deployment with the name **nginx-dns** which uses **nginx** image. I want ensure that the service and pod are accessible via their respective DNS records.

```
kubectl expose deployment nginx-dns --name=nginx-dns ...
```

or

```
kubectl expose pod nginx-dns-12234 --name=nginx-dns ...
```

Which command is better to use to ensure accessibility of pod ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fist command exposes a `deployment` and second one `pod`. It's always recommended to use `deployment` over a `pod` directly. A `deployment` is a higher level abstraction and is better from no downtime upgrade, rollout/rollback, availability and reliability perspective.

Refer to the use cases of a deployment [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#use-case)

Answer (score 1):

Deployment are easier in terms of future upgrade to your application pod. and easier to manage and recommended as best practices. Using deployment you just have to change the deployment file and rest will get updated. if you don't want to use deployment then imagine managing 100 pods and making update on them one by one is difficult and not feasible task. so hence you should always opt Deployment over Pod  directly. There are plenty of other advantages of using deployment.

For more info use the docs https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/